ASP.NET Razor Pages, passing data from the front-end script to the back-end
I am working on a project where I am using a map and need to send feedback to the backend with the current zoom level. The problem is that the page only returns a 400 Bad Request error along with "Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input."
.cshtml:
map.on('zoomend', function () {
    var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();

    // Enviar el nivel de zoom al backend
    fetch('@Url.Page("/Map", "UpdateZoom")', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(zoomLevel)
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
});

.cs:
public IActionResult OnPostUpdateZoom([FromBody] string zoom)
{
    ZoomLevel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<int>(zoom);

    int valorCapturado = ZoomLevel;


    return new JsonResult(new { success = true, receivedValue = valorCapturado });
}

Upon inspection with breakpoints, I realized that the OnPostUpdateZoom method in the backend is never being triggered. I have also verified that @Url.Page("/Map", "UpdateZoom") is generating the correct URL.

UpdateZoom is the name of the handler. You need to use the handler= syntax. There are helpers for this.

[FromBody] should already deserialise json. But your zoom variable is a string. You might want to wrap that zoom level in a json object anyway, for documentation and future expansion. But I'm confused why you are trying to mutate server state.

You haven't included the AntiForgeryToken in the Fetch request, which is why you get a 400 Bad Request status code. Since you are posting JSON data, you should send this value in the request header. Also, you need to generate the value to post.
Add @Html.AntiForgeryToken() anywhere in the Razor page which will generate a hidden field named __RequestVerificationToken then add its value to the request header:
fetch('@Url.Page("/Map", "UpdateZoom")', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'RequestVerificationToken' : document.querySelector('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').value
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(zoomLevel)
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification#ajax-post-requests-and-json

This solved it, thanks a lot!

map.getZoom() return a Number, I write an example to implement the front-end script to the back-end.I hope this helps you.
1 MyModel.cs
    public class MyModel{public int Key { get; set; }}

2 .cs
    public IActionResult OnPostUpdateZoom([FromBody] MyModel model)
        {
             return new JsonResult(
              new { success = true, receivedValue = model.Key });
        }

3  .cshtml
    $(document).ready(function () {
       var zoomLevel = 12;
       var obj = { Key: zoomLevel }
    // Enviar el nivel de zoom al backend
      fetch("?handler=UpdateZoom", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(obj)
     })
                
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    })

The result is :


I've already tried it but it still returns Bad Request, along with this object:
{type: 'basic', url: 'https://localhost:7078/Map?handler=UpdateZoom', redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, …}

builder.Services.AddRazorPages(o =>{
o.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});   Delete this configuration, my project have a 404 mistake . You can try it if you are interested.
